# interpretation of this sentence

Tags: sentence-structure

In this humorous conversation :

> A: Cows kill more people than sharks.
>
> B: I'm surprised cows kill any sharks at all.

Is interpreting A's sentence the way B did really natural?

Comment: This simply does not sound serious. Anyway, the question is not about the English language at all. Interpretation of which sentence?

Comment: One of the reasons to use the passive:  *More people than sharks are killed by cows.*

Comment: And in a world where cows don't swim in the ocean: *More people are killed by cows than (by) sharks.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it’s not natural in actual discourse—after all, that’s where the humor comes from. But of course, when it’s spoken, there’s usually an emphasis on *cows* and at least a slight emphasis on *sharks*. If it had the meaning that *B* took from it, then the main emphasis would lie on *people* instead of *cows*.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically speaking, the cited construction is perfectly valid with either parsing...

> 1: **Cows kill more people than** cows kill **sharks.**
> 2: **Cows kill more people than sharks** kill [people].

I don't think it's meaningful to ask which of those parsings is the "default". If only one makes sense, that's obviously the "correct" parsing, but if *both* make sense, the text is inherently ambiguous.

In OP's *specific* example, the joke turns on the fact that B chooses to apply an interpretation that *doesn't* make sense (#1). But that's only because it's a joke - in the real world, if A and B weren't playing roles dictated by the joke, there would be no confusion.

*In principle*, there's no scope for ambiguity in *speech*, because whichever of the first two nouns is being contrasted with ***sharks*** will be given marked stress. So the joke doesn't actually work in a real *spoken* "conversation" between native speakers. But it certainly works in the *written* form, and the auditory version may sometimes work if one or both conversants isn't a native Anglophone.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer!